# Trying to apply GBT on a set of data getting ClassCastException

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I am getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.UnresolvedAttribute$ cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.NominalAttribute".

Source code

```
package com.spark.lograthmicregression;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline;
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel;
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage;
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.GBTClassificationModel;
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.GBTClassifier;
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IndexToString;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;

import scala.collection.mutable.Seq;

public class ClickThroughRateAnalytics {

    private static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHH");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Click Analysis").setMaster("local");

        try (JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf)) {

            SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(javaSparkContext);
            DataFrame dataFrame = sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true")
                    .load("/splits/sub-suaa");

            // This will keep data in memory
            dataFrame.cache();

            // This will describe the column
            // dataFrame.describe("hour").show();

            System.out.println("Rows before removing missing data : " + dataFrame.count());

            // This will describe column details
            // dataFrame.describe("click", "hour", "site_domain").show();

            // This will calculate variance between columns +ve one increases
            // second increases and -ve means one increases other decreases
            // double cov = dataFrame.stat().cov("click", "hour");
            // System.out.println("cov : " + cov);

            // It provides quantitative measurements of the statistical
            // dependence between two random variables
            // double corr = dataFrame.stat().corr("click", "hour");
            // System.out.println("corr : " + corr);

            // Cross Tabulation provides a table of the frequency distribution
            // for a set of variables
            // dataFrame.stat().crosstab("site_id", "site_domain").show();

            // For frequent items
            // System.out.println("Frequest Items : " +
            // dataFrame.stat().freqItems(new String[] { "site_id",
            // "site_domain" }, 0.3).collectAsList());

            // TODO we can also set maximum occurring item to categorical
            // values.

            // This will replace null values with average for numeric columns
            dataFrame = modifiyDatFrame(dataFrame);

            // Removing rows which have some missing values
            dataFrame = dataFrame.na().replace(dataFrame.columns(), ImmutableMap.of("", "NA"));
            dataFrame.na().fill(0.0);
            dataFrame = dataFrame.na().drop();

            System.out.println("Rows after removing missing data : " + dataFrame.count());

            // TODO Binning and bucketing

            // normalizer will take the column created by the VectorAssembler,
            // normalize it and produce a new column
            // Normalizer normalizer = new
            // Normalizer().setInputCol("features_index").setOutputCol("features");

            dataFrame = dataFrame.drop("app_category_index").drop("app_domain_index").drop("hour_index").drop("C20_index")
                    .drop("device_connection_type_index").drop("C1_index").drop("id").drop("device_ip_index").drop("banner_pos_index");
            DataFrame[] splits = dataFrame.randomSplit(new double[] { 0.7, 0.3 });
            DataFrame trainingData = splits[0];
            DataFrame testData = splits[1];

            StringIndexerModel labelIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("click").setOutputCol("indexedclick").fit(dataFrame);
            // Here we will be sending all columns which will participate in
            // prediction
            VectorAssembler vectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(findPredictionColumns("click", dataFrame))
                    .setOutputCol("features_index");

            GBTClassifier gbt = new GBTClassifier().setLabelCol("indexedclick").setFeaturesCol("features_index").setMaxIter(10).setMaxBins(69000);

            IndexToString labelConverter = new IndexToString().setInputCol("prediction").setOutputCol("predictedLabel");
            Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(new PipelineStage[] { labelIndexer, vectorAssembler, gbt, labelConverter });

            trainingData.show(1);
            PipelineModel model = pipeline.fit(trainingData);
            DataFrame predictions = model.transform(testData);
            predictions.select("predictedLabel", "label").show(5);
            MulticlassClassificationEvaluator evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator().setLabelCol("indexedLabel")
                    .setPredictionCol("prediction").setMetricName("precision");
            double accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictions);
            System.out.println("Test Error = " + (1.0 - accuracy));

            GBTClassificationModel gbtModel = (GBTClassificationModel) (model.stages()[2]);

            System.out.println("Learned classification GBT model:\n" + gbtModel.toDebugString());

        }
    }

    private static String[] findPredictionColumns(String outputCol, DataFrame dataFrame) {
        String columns[] = dataFrame.columns();
        String inputColumns[] = new String[columns.length - 1];
        int count = 0;
        for (String column : dataFrame.columns()) {
            if (!column.equalsIgnoreCase(outputCol)) {
                inputColumns[count++] = column;
            }
        }
        return inputColumns;
    }

    /**
     * This will replace empty values with mean.
     * 
     * @param columnName
     * @param dataFrame
     * @return
     */
    private static DataFrame modifiyDatFrame(DataFrame dataFrame) {
        Set<String> numericColumns = new HashSet<String>();
        if (dataFrame.numericColumns() != null && dataFrame.numericColumns().length() > 0) {
            scala.collection.Iterator<Expression> iterator = ((Seq<Expression>) dataFrame.numericColumns()).toIterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Expression expression = iterator.next();
                Double avgAge = dataFrame.na().drop().groupBy(((AttributeReference) expression).name()).avg(((AttributeReference) expression).name())
                        .first().getDouble(1);
                dataFrame = dataFrame.na().fill(avgAge, new String[] { ((AttributeReference) expression).name() });
                numericColumns.add(((AttributeReference) expression).name());

                DataType dataType = ((AttributeReference) expression).dataType();
                if (!"double".equalsIgnoreCase(dataType.simpleString())) {
                    dataFrame = dataFrame.withColumn("temp", dataFrame.col(((AttributeReference) expression).name()).cast(DataTypes.DoubleType))
                            .drop(((AttributeReference) expression).name()).withColumnRenamed("temp", ((AttributeReference) expression).name());
                }
            }
        }

        // Fit method of StringIndexer converts the column to StringType(if
        // it is not of StringType) and then counts the occurrence of each
        // word. It then sorts these words in descending order of their
        // frequency and assigns an index to each word. StringIndexer.fit()
        // method returns a StringIndexerModel which is a Transformer
        StringIndexer stringIndexer = new StringIndexer();
        String allCoumns[] = dataFrame.columns();
        for (String column : allCoumns) {
            if (!numericColumns.contains(column)) {
                dataFrame = stringIndexer.setInputCol(column).setOutputCol(column + "_index").fit(dataFrame).transform(dataFrame);
                dataFrame = dataFrame.drop(column);
            }
        }

        dataFrame.printSchema();
        return dataFrame;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static void copyFile(DataFrame dataFrame) {
        dataFrame
                .select("id", "click", "hour", "C1", "banner_pos", "site_id", "site_domain", "site_category", "app_id", "app_domain", "app_category",
                        "device_id", "device_ip", "device_model", "device_type", "device_conn_type", "C14", "C15", "C16", "C17", "C18", "C19", "C20",
                        "C21")
                .write().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
                .save("/splits/sub-splitaa-optmized");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static Integer parse(String sDate, int field) {
        try {
            if (sDate != null && !sDate.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("hour")) {
                Date date = sdf.parse(sDate.toString());
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(date);
                return cal.get(field);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

I am using spark java. Sample file will be :

id,click,hour,C1,banner_pos,site_id,site_domain,site_category,app_id,app_domain,app_category,device_id,device_ip,device_model,device_type,device_conn_type,C14,C15,C16,C17,C18,C19,C20,C21
1000009418151094273,0,14102100,1005,0,1fbe01fe,f3845767,28905ebd,ecad2386,7801e8d9,07d7df22,a99f214a,ddd2926e,44956a24,1,2,15706,320,50,1722,0,35,-1,79
10000169349117863715,0,14102100,1005,0,1fbe01fe,f3845767,28905ebd,ecad2386,7801e8d9,07d7df22,a99f214a,96809ac8,711ee120,1,0,15704,320,50,1722,0,35,100084,79
10000371904215119486,0,14102100,1005,0,1fbe01fe,f3845767,28905ebd,ecad2386,7801e8d9,07d7df22,a99f214a,b3cf8def,8a4875bd,1,0,15704,320,50,1722,0,35,100084,79
10000640724480838376,0,14102100,1005,0,1fbe01fe,f3845767,28905ebd,ecad2386,7801e8d9,07d7df22,a99f214a,e8275b8f,6332421a,1,0,15706,320,50,1722,0,35,100084,79
10000679056417042096,0,14102100,1005,1,fe8cc448,9166c161,0569f928,ecad2386,7801e8d9,07d7df22,a99f214a,9644d0bf,779d90c2,1,0,18993,320,50,2161,0,35,-1,157
10000720757801103869,0,14102100,1005,0,d6137915,bb1ef334,f028772b,ecad2386,7801e8d9,07d7df22,a99f214a,05241af0,8a4875bd,1,0,16920,320,50,1899,0,431,100077,117
10000724729988544911,0,14102100,1005,0,8fda644b,25d4cfcd,f028772b,ecad2386,7801e8d9,07d7df22,a99f214a,b264c159,be6db1d7,1,0,20362,320,50,2333,0,39,-1,157

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?  I'm seeing the same thing with NaiveBayes.  There's a PR pending for Spark, but I don't see any activity.

Comment: Yes you have to set bin = (max distinct category count in any column) but after that I was getting stack overflow exception. May be I didn't have enough memory.

Answer (score 1):

I am late in replying but I was also facing the same error while using gbt for a dataset in csv file.
I added .setLabels(labelIndexer.labels()) in labelConverter and this solved the problem.

```
IndexToString labelConverter = new IndexToString()
                                 .setInputCol("prediction")
                                 .setOutputCol("predictedLabel")
                                 .setLabels(labelIndexer.labels())
```